# Me or I as a subject

Tags: pronouns

I am reading an example off a grammar book.

Snow white smiled at the dwarves and me/I.

"Me" or "I" should I choose and in which situation should I use me or I?

Comment: Did it really use Tolkien's word "dwarves" instead of the standard "dwarfs"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subject is "Snow White" she is the person who is smiling. "The dwarfs" and "Me" are the indirect objects of the action, and so the object form "me" is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Simplify it to:

She smiled at me/I.

and also:

I smiled at her/she.

Now without knowing much grammar, the first choices are more familiar, aren't they!